# .htaccess request to have an address served from another

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What will be a rule for .htaccess so requests pointing to `http://x.y.z.com/` will be served from `http://y.z.com/x/` (without redirect 302)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serve a request from a different host without a redirection, Apache must act as a proxy to the remote URL.

For this, you must first of all enable [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) in the server configuration.

Then you have two ways of achieving this.

### Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://y.z.com/x/$1 [P]
```

Please note that this technique uses the default connectionless proxy handling of the Apache server, which has quite poor performance.

### Using mod_proxy directives:

In your virtual host configuration, add this:

```
ProxyPass / http://y.z.com/x/
ProxyPassReverse / http://y.z.com/x/
```

The ProxyPassReverse configuration is necessary to correctly handle redirections initiated by the remote host (y.z.com in your case).

This is the recommended way to do this.

Comment: Loved your answer as I was not aware apache can be used as proxy server. But I would have rather used `varnish` to do such kind of thing.